# Pointer lost in FSEventStream Callback (ObjC and ARC)

Tags: objective-c, callback, automatic-ref-counting, nsmutabledictionary

I've had success getting the basics of FSEventStream working to allow me to watch a folder for new file events. Unfortunately, the callback reference I'm passing into FSEventStreamCreate() is being lost/corrupted/not retained so that I can't access the data object I need too. Here's the key code blocks:

**FileWatcher.m : (Setting up the FSEvent Stream)**

```
FSEventStreamContext context;
//context.info = (__bridge_retained void *)(uploadQueue);  // this didn't help
context.info = CFBridgingRetain(uploadQueue);
context.version = 0;
context.retain = NULL;
context.release = NULL;
context.copyDescription = NULL;

/* Create the stream, passing in a callback */
stream = FSEventStreamCreate(NULL,
                             &FileWatcherCallback,
                             &context,
                             pathsToWatch,
                             kFSEventStreamEventIdSinceNow, /* Or a previous event ID */
                             latency,
                             kFSEventStreamCreateFlagFileEvents /* Also add kFSEventStreamCreateFlagIgnoreSelf if lots of recursive callbacks */
                             );
```

**Filewatcher.m: FileWatcherCallback**

```
void FileWatcherCallback(
                     ConstFSEventStreamRef streamRef,
                     FSEventStreamContext *clientCallBackInfo,
                     size_t numEvents,
                     void *eventPaths,
                     const FSEventStreamEventFlags eventFlags[],
                     const FSEventStreamEventId eventIds[])
{
    int i;
    char **paths = eventPaths;

    // Retrieve pointer to the download Queue!
    NSMutableDictionary *queue = (NSMutableDictionary *)CFBridgingRelease(clientCallBackInfo->info);
    // Try adding to the queue
    [queue setValue:@"ToDownload" forKey:@"donkeytest" ];
    ...
}
```

When this callback function is fired, I can get the file paths fine, but the clientCallBackInfo->info pointer to the NSMutableDictionary is now pointing to a different memory address than it was when I set up the stream. 
When I then try and add to the dictionary, I get an exception thrown (the setValue line).

Do I need to be handling the pointers differently in some way? Any help would be MUCH appreciated.
(I'm on Xcode 4.5.1 with default build settings including ARC.)

Comment: @Steen: you should accept Martin R's answer, or explain why that doesn't solve your problem

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The second argument of the callback function is a `void *info` (which is `context.info`) and not a pointer to the `FSEventStreamContext context` structure.

So this code should work to get the correct pointer:

```
void FileWatcherCallback(
                         ConstFSEventStreamRef streamRef,
                         void *info, // <-- this is context.info
                         size_t numEvents,
                         void *eventPaths,
                         const FSEventStreamEventFlags eventFlags[],
                         const FSEventStreamEventId eventIds[])
{
    // ...
    // Retrieve pointer to the download queue:
    NSMutableDictionary *queue = CFBridgingRelease(info);
    // ...
}
```

---

**Remark:** It seems to me that there is another problem with your usage of `CFBridgingRetain()`/`CFBridgingRelease()`. The retain count of the `uploadQueue` object will be decremented *each time* the callback function is called. This causes a crash very quickly.

It is probably better to use

```
context.info = (__bridge void *)(uploadQueue);
```

for the creation of the event stream, and

```
NSMutableDictionary *queue = (__bridge NSMutableDictionary *)info;
```

in the callback function. You only have to make sure that you keep a strong reference to `uploadQueue` as long as the event stream is used.

Answer (score 0):

I've never used this API, however looking at examples on the internet, it seems normal to pass `self` in this pointer.  Then if `uploadQueue` is an instance variable you could make it accessible via a property (and have the added advantage of access to everything in your class instance).